# Count digits in file using WinApi functions

Tags: c++, winapi, createfile

I need to count digits in file using `CreateFile` and `ReadFile` methods from `<Windows.h>`.

Here's what I have:

```
int CountDigitsInFile(PCTSTR path)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        _tprintf_s(TEXT("Open File Error"));
        return NULL;
    }

    TCHAR data[100];
    DWORD dwRead;
    DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

    BOOL bResultRead = ReadFile(hFile, &data, dwFileSize, &dwRead, NULL);

    if (!bResultRead || dwRead != dwFileSize)
    {
        _tprintf_s(TEXT("Read file Error"));
        return NULL;
    }

    _tprintf_s(data); // prints the file content correctly

    int count = 0; 
    wstring str(data);    
    std::cout << str.size() << std::endl; // prints 105 when file content is       the following: Hello, World!5
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) // fails somewhere here
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            count++;  
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return count;   
}
```

Probably I'm counting them in a wrong way and I have to count byte by byte or something? And I think I really shouldn't use `wstring` here and it's better to count digits just while reading from the file.

Could you please help me with that?

#### UPDATE

Here's what I get when running the program:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the extra level of complexity of creating a std::string, you've already got it in the form of a char array, and you can make use of `dwRead`, which is the no. of bytes read by ReadFile().

```
for (int i = 0; i < dwRead; ++i)
    if (iswdigit(data[i]))
        count++;
```

Comment: when I try to run the program, I get the error for some reason. Please, look at update, there's the screenshot

Comment: I think you need to use the wide char version of `iswdigit()`

Answer (score 1):

Read following note from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55.aspx

*The size of wchar_t is implementation-defined. If your code depends on wchar_t to be a certain size, check your platform's implementation (for example, with sizeof(wchar_t)). If you need a string character type with a width that is guaranteed to remain the same on all platforms, use string, u16string, or u32string.*

If you are sure that your file does not contain any unicode or multibyte characters then its better to parse char by char